# What is the total kinetic energy of 3-link open kinematic chain joined by rotational joints? and/or how to find it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

With the help of the internet the solution I found to two links is presented below but I am having difficulty understanding how did we get the third member of uc2 namely 2*l1*lc2*cos(θ-α)* dθ*dα.

Where uc1 and uc2 is the velocity of the center of link 1 with length l1 and the velocity of the center of link 2 with length l2, respectively.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position (with respect to the origin where $l_1$ is connected to the plane) of the center of mass of $l_2$ is:
$$r_{c2}=\begin{bmatrix}
l_1\cos\theta + l_{c2}\cos\alpha\\ 
l_1\sin\theta + l_{c2}\sin\alpha\end{bmatrix}.$$ Take the derivative to get the velocity:

$$v_{c2}=\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}t}r_{c2}=\begin{bmatrix}
-l_1\dot{\theta}\sin\theta - l_{c2}\dot{\alpha}\sin\alpha\\ 
l_1\dot{\theta}\cos\theta + l_{c2}\dot{\alpha}\cos\alpha.
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The velocity squared is then:
$$
\begin{multline}\lVert v_{c2}\rVert^2=l_1^2\dot{\theta}^2\sin^2\theta+l_{c2}^2\dot{\alpha}^2\sin^2\alpha+2l_1l_{c2}\dot{\theta}\dot{\alpha}\sin\theta\sin\alpha\\
+l_1^2\dot{\theta}^2\cos^2\theta+l_{c2}^2\dot{\alpha}^2\cos^2\alpha+2l_1l_{c2}\dot{\theta}\dot{\alpha}\cos\theta\cos\alpha
\end{multline}
$$

Making use of the trigonometric identities (for all $\alpha, \beta$)

$$\sin^2 \alpha + \cos^2\alpha = 1\\
\cos(\alpha-\beta)=\cos\alpha\cos\beta+\sin\alpha\sin\beta,$$

you arrive at:
$$
\lVert v_{c2}\rVert^2=l_1^2\dot{\theta}^2+l_{c2}^2\dot{\alpha}^2+2l_1l_{c2}\dot{\theta}\dot{\alpha}\cos(\theta-\alpha)
$$